# Spring Boot application.properties custom variable in a non-controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

How come application.properties will work in a RestController, but not in a service class?

```
//application.properties
test=test
```

Works Perfect!

```
@RestController
public class invitecontroller {

    @Autowired inviteconfig inviteconfig;
    
    @PostMapping("/v1/invite")
    public void invite(@RequestBody XXX XXX) {

        System.out.println(inviteconfig);

    }
}
```

Returns "Null"

```
@Service
public class inviteservice {
    
    @Autowired inviteconfig inviteconfig;

    public void invite() {
       System.out.println(inviteconfig);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@Data
public class inviteconfig {
    private String test;
}
```

Comment: In Java we always name classes in `PascalCase`, please make sure you do so before posting questions on this site as it makes it much easier for everyone to read the code.

Comment: @Boris the Spider, thanks for your preference, but my question has nothing to do with Pascal Case thanks.

Comment: this is not a preference, this is how Java is written.

Comment: **Do not** update your question with the “fixed” code!  Now the answers don’t make sense, because they appear to be addressing something that isn’t in your question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inviteservice` class is not configured for Spring IoC (Inversion of Control) as a bean, so Spring will not handle the `inviteservice` class lifecycle. In this case, `@Autowired` is useless.

To fix this try to add `@Component` annotation to `invitesevice`, to declare it as a component:

```
@Component
public class inviteservice {
    
    @Autowired inviteconfig inviteconfig;

    public void invite() {
       System.out.println(inviteconfig);
    }
}
```

In the case of the controller, with `@RestController`, Spring will recognize your class as a Spring component.

Finally, don't forget to inject `inviteservice` using Spring IoC (using `@Autowired` annotation, or other means)

Comment: I'll be damned, I sat here for days playing with this, but the key for me was that I was calling inviteservice `inviteservice inviteservice = new inviteservice()` in the controller, but had to adjust it to read `@autowired inviteservice inviteservice` in conjunction with the @Service/@Component.

Answer (score 0):

inviteservice class should be annotated with @Component or @Service

```
@Component 
public class inviteservice { 
...
```